# Avoid importing parent packages when running unittests in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

I have a problem with python importing parent packages.

Consider a unit test such as:

```
import unittest

from parent.child.grandchildren import some_code

class SomeCodeTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_that_some_code_get_stuff_done(self):
        self.assertEqual(some_code("stuff"), "stuff done")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Now, if `parent/__init__.py` for example contains:

```
import os

foo = os.environ["AN_ENV_VARIABLE"]
```

My unit tests will fail if that variable is not set because python imports parent packages. **Is there some way to get around this without modifying the production code?** I just want to import that unit and just that unit no matter how ugly or wrong neighbouring code might be.

Comment: You can do like os.environ.get("AN_ENV_VARIABLE"). This wouldn't break even when it is not set in env.

Comment: Besides the point. I am talking about any bad code in any parent module to the code that is being tested can break the test suite. I want the tests to run independent of parent packages, or even other modules in the same package. Is this not possible in python?

Comment: You can run your test independently if they haven't any dependency on other module.In your case, you are importing function from parent module that would also run the __init__ file during importing.

Comment: That is not true at all. Python import parents to child packages regardless of child package dependencies. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#regular-packages

Comment: Above statement stating the same, what the doc is saying i.e importing parent module would execute the init file during importing. This is what I was saying. Let me know if I'm thinking something else.

Comment: I think you try something, that you should not do.

without cheating / messing around with the python path etc.

all `__init__.py` of all parents will always be imported.
It's kind of how python modules are working

You can set the python path to the base directory of the file, that you want to test and import it, but as I said I'm not sure that's a good idea